# extracting rows from CSV file based on specific keywords

Tags: python, csv, extract, operator-keyword

[image]

I have created a code to help me retrieving the data from csv file

```
  import re
keywords = {"metal", "energy", "team", "sheet", "solar" "financial", "transportation", "electrical", "scientists",
            "electronic", "workers"}  # all your keywords


keyre=re.compile("energy",re.IGNORECASE)
with open("2006-data-8-8-2016.csv") as infile:
    with open("new_data.csv", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(infile.readline())  # Save the header
        for line in infile:
            if len(keyre.findall(line))>0:
                outfile.write(line)
```

I need it to look for each keyword in two main columns which are "position" and "Job description" , and then take the whole row that includes these words and write them in the new file. Any ideas on how this can be done in the simplest way?

Comment: I need it to look at all keywords, for example it should look for the rows that include "metal" word under "position" and "job description", and extract the whole rows and write them in the file, then look for the second word and do the same until the last word

Answer (score 1):

Try this, looping in a dataframe and write back a new dataframe to a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

keywords = {"metal", "energy", "team", "sheet", "solar", "financial", 
        "transportation", "electrical", "scientists",
        "electronic", "workers"}  # all your keywords

df = pd.read_csv("2006-data-8-8-2016.csv", sep=",")

listMatchPosition = []
listMatchDescription = []

for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if any(x in df['position'][i] or x in df['Job description'][i] for x in keywords):
        listMatchPosition.append(df['position'][i])
        listMatchDescription.append(df['Job description'][i])


output = pd.DataFrame({'position':listMatchPosition, 'Job description':listMatchDescription})
output.to_csv("new_data.csv", index=False)
```

EDIT:
If you have many columns to add, the modified following code will do the job.

```
df = pd.read_csv("2006-data-8-8-2016.csv", sep=",")

output = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if any(x in df['position'][i] or x in df['Job description'][i] for x in keywords):
    output.loc[len(output)] = [df[j][i] for j in df.columns]

output.to_csv("new_data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Note that this will work also if "Job description" isn't only one word, as I assume it is not, contrary to the Dataframe.isin method

Comment: the csv file includes other columns as well that I need to extract and put in the new file. Any idea on how to this?  @Vincent K

Comment: You mean columns like "Salary", "Location" that need to be extracted together? If yes, and if it's just a few columns more, just add more listMatchxxx

Comment: yes there are more 18 columns that need to be extracted like salary, education and extra. I'll give it a try and see what will I get! thank you  @Vincent K

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using pandas as follows, if you are looking for rows that contain exactly one word from the list of keywords:

```
keywords = ["metal", "energy", "team", "sheet", "solar" "financial", "transportation", "electrical", "scientists",
            "electronic", "workers"]

# read the csv data into a dataframe 
# change "," to the data separator in your csv file 
df = pd.read_csv("2006-data-8-8-2016.csv", sep=",")
# filter the data: keep only the rows that contain one of the keywords 
# in the position or the Job description columns
df = df[df["position"].isin(keywords) | df["Job description"].isin(keywords)] 
# write the data back to a csv file 
df.to_csv("new_data.csv",sep=",", index=False)
```

If you are looking for substrings in the rows (e.g looking `financial` in `financial engineering`) then you can do the following:

```
keywords = ["metal", "energy", "team", "sheet", "solar" "financial", "transportation", "electrical", "scientists",
            "electronic", "workers"]
searched_keywords = '|'.join(keywords)

# read the csv data into a dataframe 
# change "," to the data separator in your csv file 
df = pd.read_csv("2006-data-8-8-2016.csv", sep=",")
# filter the data: keep only the rows that contain one of the keywords 
# in the position or the Job description columns
df = df[df["position"].str.contains(searched_keywords) | df["Job description"].str.contains(searched_keywords)] 
# write the data back to a csv file 
df.to_csv("new_data.csv",sep=",", index=False)
```

Comment: this is simple and seems good, I got the code. But it doesn't save any data only the headers :( although i'm sure that a lot of keywords are included in the file specifically in position and job description @MedAli

Comment: @Eng.Reem can you share a sample of your data ?

Comment: This won't work, because the "Job description" column isn't only one word.

Comment: @VincentK, the "Job description" colum is only a selector label it has nothing to do with whether it's going to work or not.

Comment: @MedAli I meant, each row in the "Job description" column will not contain just one word. If it is written "This job consists in taking financial decisions", it won't match any keyword even though "financial" is in the sentence, Dataframe.isin takes the row item as a whole.

Comment: @Eng.Reem check the updated answer with str.contains

Comment: @VincentK I see what you mean, check my updated answer with str.contains