# Check if string exists in multiple csv files and write row to file

Tags: python, csv, if-statement, awk, match

I got this project where I want to check if an e-mail address exists in two or more csv files. The number of files can vary, also their prefix, but they will always be stored in the same directory.

I need help with the following

1. A method for finding a match in two or more files.
2. Search a whole directory at once
3. write  all the rows where the matching address exists to a new file.
4. Point me in the direction where I can put this to use in a script where I can use it with a "if" statement and together with a webb app.

I have had a look at

[extracting rows from CSV file based on specific keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903691/extracting-rows-from-csv-file-based-on-specific-keywords)

But that would require me to know what e-mail address I am looking for which I don´t.

For the one with loads of time, in the essay below you can find what I have "achieved" so far and example of original file and desired output.

Example of original file that will be checked. The number of rows can vary. The e-mail address can also occasionally be found in other columns than column 1. Therefore maybe a keyword method is suggested? This is something I have not yet accomplished.

```
example.csv
IP ADDRESS, FIRST TIME LOGGED IN, LAST TIME LOGGED IN, USERNAME
192.168.1.1 , 2018-03-07 11:33:22, 2018-03-07 11:33:28, Federov
E-MAIL ADDRESS, FIRST TIME LOGGED IN, LAST TIME LOGGED IN, USERNAME, 
schultz@mail.com, 2018-03-07 09:33:22, 2018-03-07 11:33:28, Boris Becker
```

The desired outcome is something like the below, both for the saved file and for the webb app.

```
Result.csv
Match
E-MAIL ADDRESS, FIRST TIME LOGGED IN, LAST TIME LOGGED IN, USERNAME
schultz@mail.com, 2018-03-07 09:33:22, 2018-03-07 11:33:28, Boris Becker
schultz@mail.com, 2017-01-07 14:56:12, 2018-01-18 18:44:03, McEnroe
```

This is what I got so far:

I tried putting my "step by step" method into a string. I ran this string in a  folder where I had two .csv files with one matching address. However I received zero, nothing, nada.. No error message and no nothing in the file.  The string looks like the following:

```
awk '/E-MAIL/{y=1;next}y' *.csv | awk '{print $1}' FS="," | awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1];next}$1 in arr{print $1,"match"}' > results.csv
```

Step by step it works but it´s a grueling job doing this for every file. I also have to create new files to make it work.

```
awk '/E-MAIL/{y=1;next}y' file-0A.csv > /test/file-0B.csv`
awk '{print $1}' FS="," file-0B.csv > /test/file-1A.csv
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1];next}$1 in arr{print $1,"match"}' file-1A.csv file-1B.csv > /test/results.csv
```

Except for being ridiculous tedious and probably plain stupid, this method or at least in it´s current state, only allow a match to be done between two files, adding a third  will make it look like the match needs to be found in all three files not in any two which is required...

Also, the current method ( if you even can call it a method) does not allow to have the additional information together with the e-mail address when doing the match step,  since this will then match for example date or time.. I have not the knowledge either to use this output for a "if" statement..

The OS is Raspian Stretch with root privileges.

I apologize if I have not included any vital information, misspelled or put this question in a wrong way.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Some quick comments: `awk '/E-MAIL/{y=1;next}y'` will print every line after the first `/E-MAIL/`, you never reset `y` to `0`. Second, you mention that the email might appear in any column, so how do you get the header correct?

Comment: Good point, the columns will vary but the csv files will always have a column with the header "E-MAIL ADDRESS"

Comment: Other questions: Do you want to check if emails in `file0` are in `file1` .. `filen`. Or do you want to check if `file0` ... `filen` have duplicate emails. On top of that, your example `Result.csv` has a clear header which might not match if the email is in another field. The point is, it is a bit unclear what you request.

Comment: Ok, sorry if it was unclear what i requested. To boil it down; check if an emails exists in multiple csv files regardless of the csv filename (filen,file0 etc). If is found i more than one file, write the email to a new file. Preferably the entire row where the email exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done in Python 2.x as follows:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
from collections import defaultdict
import glob    
import csv

fieldnames = ['E-MAIL ADDRESS', 'FIRST TIME LOGGED IN', 'LAST TIME LOGGED IN', 'USERNAME']
emails = defaultdict(list)

for csv_filename in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    with open(csv_filename, 'rb') as f_input:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f_input, fieldnames=fieldnames, skipinitialspace=True)
        next(dropwhile(lambda x: x['E-MAIL ADDRESS'] != 'E-MAIL ADDRESS', csv_reader))

        for row in csv_reader:
            emails[row['E-MAIL ADDRESS']].append(row)


with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
    csv_writer.writeheader()

    for email, rows in sorted(emails.items()):
        if len(rows) > 1:
            csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

This uses the `glob.glob()` function to give you a list of `.csv` files. It writes all email addresses to `output.csv` where the email address is seen more than once across all CSV files found. It skips all lines until the line starting `E-MAIL ADDRESS` is found.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. I receive the following error: ` sudo python script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: You are using Python 2.x, I have updated it to work on this.

Comment: Great! Just to be clear, I do not know what specific address I am looking for.  I am looking for any duplicates that might exist. So I dont have that match = "e-mail address" that is specified in the beginning of the script. Will this work anayway? Again, tank you for taking your time!

Comment: To list all duplicates (i.e. found more than once) across all files would require different logic and would require all data to be read in before the output file is created.

Comment: Ok, I thank you for your help so far. I will look further if you can´t point me in a general direction?

Comment: Try the updated code. This might do what you are looking for.

Comment: That's because not all your CSV files have matching column headings. It should now ignore that problem using `extrasaction='ignore'`

Comment: Getting there, it now skips all lines until the `E-MAIL ADDRESS` line is found.

Comment: You Sir, are a genius! Great job! I will mark your reply as an answer. The other coder works brilliant as well but is missing the headers which you included! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all files in a directory:

```
import os
file list = os.listdir()
```

You need to open all files in the list and wrie all e-mail adresses to a dictionary. Like so:

```
my_dict[e_mail] = my_dict.get(e_mail, 0) + 1
```

This will give you a count of how often a mail address occurs. Then you can write all addresses to your outfile that occur more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` is a one-pass programm and should do the trick :

```
 awk '# The BEGIN statement sets the field separator FS
      BEGIN{FS="[[:blank:]]*,[[:blank:]]*"}

      # If the word "E-MAIL" is not found, skip to the next line
      !/E-MAIL/{next}

      # The line contains "E-MAIL"
      { 
        # Find the column of the email
        for(col=1;col<=NF;col++) { if (match($col,"E-MAIL")) break; }
        getline;      # retrieve the next line 
        email=$col;   # set the email to the value
        p[email]++;   # count the occurance of "email"
      }

      # if we have more then 2 email occurances
      # print the line to f[email] and skip to the next line
      (p[email]>2) { print > f[email]; next }

      # if this is the first time we have email
      # store the full line in l[email]
      (p[email]==1){l[email]=$0}

      # if this is the second time we find email
      (p[email]==2){
         # create filename
         f[email]=email".txt";sub(/@/,"_at_",f[email]);
         # print first line to f[email]
         print l[email]>f[email];
         # print current line to f[email]
         print > f[email]
      }' *.csv
```

What this does is everytime it finds the word "E-MAIL", it searches for the field number where the word occurs, reads the next line and retrieves the `email`address.

Then it does some logic, it keeps track of how many times `email` occured.

- If it is the first time, it stores the line in `l[email]`
- If it is the second line, it creates a filename `f[email]` that looks like `"foo_at_bar.com.txt"`, prints the first line `l[email]` in that file, and the current line.
- If it is the third or more time, it just prints the line to `f[email]`.

This creates you all the files.

Comment: This works brilliantly! However it is missing the headers in the output file. I know this is just minor adjustment to get this fixed. I would like to mark this as an answer as well, but since I am limited to only one, the below will receive my anser since it have all the features. Thank you for your time and effort!