# CSV Text Read/Write into new file based on keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to extract certain words, I have defined as keywords by reading a single column in one file and creating a new column with these words (if present)...

So far, I have:

```
import pandas as pd

keywords= {"these", "are", "my", "keywords", "defined"} 

df = pd.read_csv("this_is_my_file.csv", sep= ",")
```

.... and now I am stuck. Thoughts? I found this thread ([extracting rows from CSV file based on specific keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903691/extracting-rows-from-csv-file-based-on-specific-keywords)) and I was able to get it to write the column headers but not on each row based on the key value.

> Edit: I have a lot of keywords was was able to define each (over 1k).
>   I have over 1k "Content" rows to iterate through to search for my
>   keywords.

```
Keywords: {"cake", "pie", "sugar"}

Original:

ID    contents            
123   This is pie         
1234  Cake be with you

Desired outcome:

ID    contents            new col  

123   This is             Pie  
1234  be with you         Cake
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a little unclear what you are after here. Do you want to read your CSV file into a dataframe, and then create a new column based on your keywords? And if so, what should the new column contain? Or, do you want to only read certain rows from the CSV into your dataframe, based again on your keywords. It is also helpful if you provide a sample of your input file, and an example of the output you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Let me clarify.. I have two files (Test_Desc.csv) with two columns, one with descriptions and a  separate ID column. The description may or may not contain my keywords I have defined (it is possible that it may hit more than one). I would like to read my Test_Desc.csv into the data frame and then create a new column with the keyword (preferably extracted from the description). 
Example: keywords {"cake", "sugar", "spice"}
ID Description                           New Column
1  This is my cake description  Cake
2  Sugar Spice are nice            Sugar, Spice

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, if i understood your question correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
keywords = ['a', 'b']

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['keywords'] = ['1', 'a', 'd', 'b']
df['contents'] = ['foo','foo','foo','foo',]

filtered_df = df[df['keywords'].isin(keywords)]
```

In the last line we use df[*condition*] structure to filter the dataframe. Additionally, we use pandas.isin() function on a series (a column) to match it with the keyword list. 
The resulting dataframe only has rows that match this filter. 
        keywords    contents
    1   a   foo
    3   b   foo

Updated the answer to create a new column with the filtered values:

```
import pandas as pd
keywords = ['a', 'b']

def check_keywords(x):
    if x in keywords:
        return x
    return None

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['keywords'] = ['1', 'a', 'd', 'b']
df['contents'] = ['foo','foo','foo','foo',]

df['extracted_keywords']= df['keywords'].apply(check_keywords)
```

To achieve that we use a lambda function called by pd.apply().
Lambda function is essentially a heavily optimized for loop that is executed on every row of the series.

Comment: Thanks. I think we are getting there, sorry my table didn't come out structured. What I am missing is that my description file contains hundreds of lines anywhere from 8-500 characters, so I cannot define each line. I have my keywords defined, can df['contents'] reference a column header and loop through each line inserting the keyword where present in a new column (the rest being null)?

Comment: Updated the answer, to fit your comment~

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure I understand exactly what you are after here. It doesn't make sense to me that you'd want to remove the keywords from your description, as implied by your output. Anyway, here is one way to produce a column that has keywords that match the corresponding description. You are likely going to need to clean the text in your description column, my example doesn't have any punctuation for example. Feel free to ask another question on that topic.

```
import pandas as pd

keywords = {'sugar', 'spice'}

data = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'description': ['My cake contains sugar', 'My cake contains spice', 'My cake has sugar and spice', 'My cake has only flour']})

data['keyword_match'] = pd.Series([[*j.intersection(keywords)] for j in [set(i) for i in data['description'].str.split()]]).apply(', '.join)

data
```

Gives:

[image]